# Lumia 535 video audio fm sound stops suddenly

Tags: nokia-lumia-535, headset

My Lumia 535 video, audio, FM sound stops within 10 seconds from the start, when I am using use headset. My phone plays video,audio fine with the speakers. Problem occurs only when headset is used. Video, audio pauses when the sound stops if headset is used. Is it due to loose headset contact? I have tried 3 headsets, all having the same problem, the headsets are fine. It is really bothering me. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the headset as you have mentioned using 3 different headsets. **The problem may be in your phones audio jack.**

As far as I see any software errors such as turning on battery saver mode will affect playing music via speaker phone also.

The only viable solution may be to take your phone to nearest Service centre.